# Why do AWS elastic beanstalk rolling version updates still have a 2min downtime with 503s?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, high-availability

We're deploying a war to an elastic beanstalk setup with two instances.

I set the batch size to 1 fixed, and command timeout to 15m.

I'm expecting the instance to be removed from the ELB, updated, added back, then when it returns to InService beanstalk should repeat the process for the next instance. Instead I end up with zero healthy instances for a few minutes.

There are no other timeouts or anything I can set, so I'm wondering if our slow app startup (1m30s) is causing trouble with hardcoded timeouts?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but anyway.

Unfortunately, the 'rolling updates' on Elastic Beanstalk only apply to configuration changes, and not to code deployments as per comment from Amazon on this thread.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=502158

Alternative deployment strategies are detailed here:
http://www.hudku.com/blog/demystified-zero-downtime-with-amazon/

There is opportunity to improve AWS deployment by adding/removing EC2 instances from loadbalancer but this does not fall within the Elastic Beanstalk functionality. Instead swapping CNAME records is recommended which can leave meaningful traffic still on the old instances.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it may have just been a bug with an old EB deployment not working with the new rolling version updates feature. Once I rebuilt the nodes the rolling version updates started working perfectly without any downtime.